# Monogame vs ANX vs Delta engine

Tags: windows-8

I am looking for a Win8-Metro-friendly framework for my next game project. Two of the non-commercial options are Monogame and ANX. Both are XNA like. I am wondering which one is more mature and reliable?

And I've already just heard about the "Delta Engine" framework, which seems like another good alternative.

What are the pros and cons of these three options?

Comment: Which technology to use questions are off topic for the site. Read the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) to see what types of questions to ask here. You need to study what the technologies have to offer and decide which one suits the requirements of your project.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, MonoGame is the oldest and most mature project, but it is pretty low level. The DeltaEngine does not really care if you use XNA, OpenGL, DirectX or frameworks with the same API (MonoGame, ANX, it tries to work with those frameworks, not against it) or any framework on top (SharpDX).

Delta Engine is still early in beta, but for those who want to try it out a release is coming later this month, which supports Windows 8 and Windows Phone. While in beta Delta Engine is also free to use for everyone and any beta platform, so why not try it out and see if it helps you.

Disclaimer: I was an XNA MVP from 2006-2010, also some of the ANX guys are now working for the Delta Engine. And I am the CEO of the Delta Engine ^^

Answer (score 1):

I guess MonoGame is definetely more mature project than both ANX and DeltaEngine combined, with a stable builds and large user base. Also [DeltaEngine license](http://deltaengine.net/About/License) prohibits free usage on platform other than Windows.